# What is the correct way to assert relationships between const variables

Tags: c#, constants

I have a class that is used to author some animations in a game engine. The of the variables of that animation are authored as `const float`'s like so:

```
const float firstAnimationDuration = 3f;
const float secondAnimationDelay = 1f;
const float secondAnimationDuration = 1f;
```

In this example the first animation will take 3 seconds to complete, and a sub animation will begin 1 second after the first animation begins and take 1 second to complete.

The animation code is built assuming that `secondAnimation` will finish before `firstAnimation` - and in this case it will. If the second animation is still running when the first is finished then the system may behave unpredictably.

The problem is that it's likely that someone else will edit these `const float`'s at a later date and I need a good way to warn them of these requirements.

I've added comments explaining the requirements but ideally I would add some kind of console error, or better yet compile time error.

I tried the following code in class initializer:

```
if (secondAnimationDelay + secondAnimationDuration > firstAnimationDuration)
{
    Debug.LogError ("Second animation cannot be longer than First Animation");
}
```

But this results in a compile time warning saying that the `Debug.LogError` is unreachable code (which makes sense!), but in this case the warning is guarding against compile time problems, not runtime errors, so it's *supposed* to be unreachable.

Given that I would rather not have a warning left in my console every time I build, what would be the best way to guard against changes to these `const` values to avoid unintended consequences?

Comment: A comment, there's not much more you can do.

Comment: How about parameterizing the class by accepting this values and putting your validation in the constructor?

Comment: You could also write a unit-test that ensures these things make sense.

Comment: That will totally void the idea of compile time constants. And unit tests are something the user has to run, too - but yes, this is about the best you can do.

Comment: How about silencing the warning with `#pragma warning`?

Comment: Can you use a MessageBox or a log file ?

Comment: @Sweeper this sounds like the most elegant solution so far. I'm usually a little nervous to disable warnings but this seems like a legitimate use.

Comment: @OlivierRogier Sadly the problem would still persist that any code that wrote to a log file or showed a MessageBox would still generate a generate an `Unreachable Code` warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On balance this seems to be a legitimate use case for `#pragma warning disable` like so.

```
if (secondAnimationDelay + secondAnimationDuration > firstAnimationDuration)
{
#pragma warning disable  
    Debug.LogError ("Second animation cannot be longer than First Animation");
#pragma warning restore
}
```